# What are the minimum systems required for a cross platform College News Paper mobile app?

Tags: mobile, server, cross-platform

I will try to be brief and specific here. I want to build a mobile cross platform College News app (that serves android and IOS) which can be used by students at my school of 2,000. This app would likely serve about 500 - 1000 people at its peak and I'm thinking it would have a worker from the news paper office update the articles that go within the app. For its first iteration I want it to be simple as possible.

I was wondering what are the minimum physical or software systems required to make this happen? Currently I think I will need: Google Login API, the app it self, and a server to populate data. Am I missing anything else here? Would I need a database or a physical computer server to support the app? Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution to handle thousands of clients and a server would be to use web technologies. Take a look at Apache Cordova. This is a cross platform solution for iOS, Android and Windows Phone.

Firebase could help you to upload and download news from and to subscribers.